# Issues with building Customer Handler for authentication

Tags: maven, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using the code from the following example.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Writing+Custom+Handlers

I am not able to compile the code. I have the latest libraries apache synapse library from maven. However the classorg.apache.synapse.rest.AbstractHandler is not be found in the library.

Would like to know which Maven repo and artificats I need to use to get the sample code working.

MY goal is to connect with the backend database for authntication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this dependecy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
    <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2-wso2v8</version>
</dependency>
```

And add this repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2</id>
      <name>wso2</name>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Udate**

You will need this dependency also:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Added the above dependency. Still getting compilation error on MessageContext and APISecurityException. Trying to upload picture of the error but looks like ther eis no way to do it in StackOverflow.

Comment: add stacktrace. lets see

Comment: Here is the link to the error: 1)POM: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ssautherrors/wso2pom.PNG  2)Eclipse IDE error: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ssautherrors/ws02autherror1.PNG

Comment: The MessageContext is definately there.. try to clean your project. In which package you expect to have APISecurityException?

Comment: Added dependency that has APISecurityException

Comment: Thank you. The APISecurityException has been resolved. I am still getting the MessageContex error though I see that class in wso2 synapse core. Very weird. Eclipse is giving the following errors.
1)` Description Resource Path Location Type
The type org.apache.synapse.MessageContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files CustomHandler.java /customhandler/src/main/java/com/test/auth/customhandler line 1 Java Problem `

Comment: Right click on the project.. then Maven -> Update Project.. sometimes helps

Comment: And F5.. if all of this doesnt help.. remove and import the project again

Answer (score 0):

We went a different route. We extended  JDBCUserStoreManager that worked better for us. Thanks for all the input.